# CopyLocal in a Visual Studio 2005 ASP.NET Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, resources

Is there something like the Reference property **CopyLocal** in a Visual Studio 2005 **ASP.NET Web Site**?

A VS05 **Web Application** has a References folder in the **Solution Explorer** where you can select a reference and view its properties, such as CopyLocal, in the Properties window.

But a VS05 **Web Site** only has a References folder in the **Class View**, where you can't access any properties for the references. Is there another simple way to set properties on your references in a Web Site? Or are the reference DLLs automatically copied when you publish a Web Site onto a machine other than your own?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The website project has a Bin folder that is copied to the root of the site when you publish.

**Edit:** Reread your question.  The answer is yes, references are automatically copied when you publish.  You can see the references in the bin folder